# How are is the seekbar in main.xml linked to the java file? Programming in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm taking an Android class based on this book:
http://www.deitel.com/Books/Android/AndroidforProgrammers/tabid/3606/Default.aspx

I'm working on the TipCalculator example, though it's been modified by the professor I think (to make it work with the new versions and he got the project most of the way done.  It's TipCalculator-partial-layout.zip).  I don't understand the concepts of how the stuff in the java file knows what seekbar to listen to.  Can someone explain it to me?  I've been told it has to do with the id, but I don't understand what that means.

This is a snippet from the main.xml file regarding the seekbar:

```
<SeekBar
          android:id="@+id/customSeekBar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_span="2"
          >

</SeekBar>
```

This is a snippet from the main.xml file regarding the seekbar:

```
(part of onCreate)
// get the SeekBar used to set the custom tip amount
      SeekBar customSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.customSeekBar);
      customSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);
```

Then there's the listener object:

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListener = 
      new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
   {
      // update currentCustomPercent, then call updateCustom
      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
         boolean fromUser) 
      {
         // sets currentCustomPercent to position of the SeekBar's thumb
         currentCustomPercent = seekBar.getProgress();
         updateCustom(); // update EditTexts for custom tip and total
      } // end method onProgressChanged

      @Override
      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
      {
      } // end method onStartTrackingTouch

      @Override
      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
      {
      } // end method onStopTrackingTouch
   }; // end OnSeekBarChangeListener
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this xml:

```
<SeekBar
      android:id="@+id/customSeekBar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_span="2"
      >
```

There's a line that says "@+id/customSeekBar". That line approximately meands "add an android id with the name 'customseekbar'.

Then, in the java code, you're calling:

```
SeekBar customSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.customSeekBar);
```

Which says: find the android view with the id "customSeekBar" (from the XML) and cast it as a SeekBar, since findViewById returns a more generic View.

Then you can call all your java methods on it, like assigning listeners.

---

Does this make sense?

It might be worth looking into an "android basics", "android for beginners" or "getting started with android" book.

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  I had thought that this class was going to be an intro to Android, but it seems otherwise. :-/

Comment: I've taken an "introductory" Android programming course before. A lot of teachers forget to mention these details because they become very natural after awhile. Keep at it though. The fact that youre going out of your way to figure things out on StackOverflow is the sign of a good mobile dev.

Answer (score 0):

If you put an element in your layout (e.g. `SeekBar`) with the id `"@+id/customSeekBar"`, it will be mapped in the code to `R.id.customSeekBar`. This "magic" is done by the `R` automatically generated file. Thus `findViewById(R.id.customSeekBar)` can be used to reach exactly that layout element.

The `R` file (located in the `/gen` folder) can map layout elements (called views - for example `R.id.myView`), layouts themselves (`R.layout.myLayout`), predefined strings (`R.string.my_string`), and other elements you will learn in due time.

Answer (score 0):

If you change something in the XML files, Java classes are generated from that. If an item has an id you can look it up. The class where all the ids are stored is named `R`

So if you execute

```
SeekBar customSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.customSeekBar);
```

You are getting the numeric id for `customSeekBar` from the `R` class and looking for the component with that id, which is your `SeekBar`. In the next line you just use that `SeekBar` and add a listener to it.

`android:id="@+id/customSeekBar"` declares the name of your `SeekBar` that we have used before. If you change it to e.g. `android:id="@+id/foo"` you would get your `SeekBar` with

```
SeekBar customSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.foo);
```